# how to set limit on table containing record

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL
Is there any way to set limit of table record/row? I have table X and want to set limit of total records/rows on table, for example 2rows. So no one can insert third record in table. This table should not allow to insert third record. 
I do not want to use Triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this the user grants, so the user cant write into this table and you can create a separate User for administration this table.

seee Manual : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/grant/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use triggers, you 'll have to check the number of rows inside your application (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Create an AFTER INSERT trigger on the table. - it's the only way to do it.

```
create trigger TableLimit
on TableName
after insert
as
    declare @countTableRows int
    select @countTableRows = Count(*)
    from TableName

    if @countTableRows > 2
    begin
        rollback
    end
go
```